# how to place cursor in textinput in Flex3

Tags: apache-flex

how to place cursor in a text input when user login form comes. I want cursor place in username text input. .Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go along with J_A_X's answer, if you're trying to set focus on a component when the application first loads, you'll also need to [use some javascript to set the focus on your SWF](http://www.webappsolution.com/wordpress/2010/08/31/set-flex-to-focus-on-application-load/).

Here's the sample code from that article:

**The Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onFlexInitialized()
{
    //alert("onFlexInitialized");

    <!-- Force the browser to set flex app with focus -->
    document.getElementById("${application}").focus();
}
</script>
```

**The ActionScript:**

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public function AppController()
{
    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, onAppComplete); // Flex 4
        //Application.application.addEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, onAppComplete); // Flex 3
}

/**
 * Handles the application complete event.
 */
protected function onAppComplete(e:FlexEvent):void
{
    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, onAppComplete); // Flex 4
        //Application.application.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, onAppComplete); // Flex 3

    if(ExternalInterface.available)
    {
        ExternalInterface.call("onFlexInitialized");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You @Jason Towne. Previously, I dont know how use action script thats why I did not go with your answer. I could not do it and finally using javascript, I did it. Thanks again :).

Answer (score 1):

You can't manually move the mouse cursor, however, you can always set the focus on the TextInput after your form is complete:

```
<mx:Canvas creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">
   <mx:Script>
      <![CDATA[
         private function onCreationComplete():void
         {
            input.setFocus();
         }
      ]]>
   </mx:Script>
   <mx:TextInput id="input" />
</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: Thank for the explanation with code @J_A_X but the text input is highlighting and I'm not getting cursor over there.

Comment: As I said in my answer "You can't manually move the mouse cursor".

Comment: You dint get me @J_A_X. When the form is first loaded, Username textinput is highlighting but I cant see cursor there. Even if I type without placing the cursor on it, I cant see the text. It means by default the cursor is not placing in the text input.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Label id="laa" x="264" y="118" width="160"/>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            [Bindable]
            private var tempArr:Array;
            private function myFunc(event:TextEvent):void{
            tempArr=new Array();

                for(var i:int=0, j:int=0;i<myarr.length;i++){
                if(myarr[i].names.toString().match(textinput.text)){
                        tempArr[j]=myarr[i];
                        j++;
                }else{

                }
                }
                ls.dataProvider=tempArr;
                ls.visible=true;

            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>


    <mx:Array id="myarr">
        <mx:Object names="Subudhi"/>
        <mx:Object names="Subbu"/>
        <mx:Object names="Harish"/>
        <mx:Object names="Hari"/>
        <mx:Object names="Subramanyam"/>
        <mx:Object names="Suresh"/>
        <mx:Object names="Surya"/>
        <mx:Object names="Harsha"/>
        <mx:Object names="Geetha"/>
        <mx:Object names="Gentle"/>
        <mx:Object names="gentleman"/>
        <mx:Object names="sunny"/>
        <mx:Object names="sunday"/>
    </mx:Array>
    <mx:TextInput id="textinput" x="264" y="10" textInput="myFunc(event)" focusOut="ls.visible=false"/>
    <mx:List  id="ls" x="264" y="31" height="66"   visible="false" labelField="names" width="160" backgroundColor="#F3EBEB"></mx:List>
</mx:Application>

    enter code here
```

Comment: A description to go along with this would be beneficial to not only the person asking the question, but anybody else who also has the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("javascript: document.getElementById('XXX').focus();"), "_self"); 
userNameInput.setFocus();
```

Where XXX is the name of the swf file.

Answer (score -1):

ON Adobe forum, solution is provider for almost same issue 
please ck

[How to move the cursor in a text input programatically](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2253226)

Hopes that helps

Comment: -1 That post doesn't apply the OPs question. He wants to know how to automatically set the focus on the username TextInput field when the form is first loaded.